# canOpenURL return true and app is installed but app is not opening

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, custom-scheme-url

when I using `canOpenURL` to open universal link, (target app is installed)

`canOpenURL` return true, but app is not opening (`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` are not registered)

but if I use `open(_ url, options)` app is opening

If I am responsible for not registering `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, how do I register Universal's links to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`? (https://www.aaa.com)

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>https://www.aaa.com</string>
</array>
```

like this?

Comment: Are you the owner of https://www.aaa.com ?

Comment: @CZ54 no i’m not. 

But the client gave us that universal links

Comment: To make universal ink work, you need to put a file on the server. If you are not the owner, it won't work

Comment: But open(_:, options) can open that link

Comment: Of course, you can open any well-formed url. Doesn't mean YOUR app will open it. It means iOS knows a way to open it ( another app, safari, etc )

Answer (score 2):

If AAA is the app that you're trying to open, there is another way to launch it from inside your app.  You will need to grab the `CFBundleURLSchemes` that the target app uses.
For AAA its "aaamobile"
For AAA Auto Club its "aaamobileace"

You then need to add the url schemes into your plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>aaamobile</string>
</array>
```

And then in your code you can check to see if the app is installed and launch the app or take user to website:

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "aaamobile://") else { return }
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.aaa.com")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Comment: How can we find out the `CFBundleURLSchemes` that those apps use?

Comment: @lavta3 I have a jailbroken device that I can use for testing purposes, so its super simple to pull those values if they exist.  If you do not have a JB device, you can still find the same info by downloading the .ipa file and extracting the contents.  I don't want to link to any tutorials as they might change, but a simple google search should yield the proper result.